# Trying to fetch a list of all my beacons nearby. but nothing is returned

Tags: android, beacon, ibeacon-android, estbeaconmanager

I have all the permissions granted.
I use the beaconManager. which I create like this:

```
 beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
            setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_UID_LAYOUT));
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
            setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_TLM_LAYOUT));
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
            setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_URL_LAYOUT));
    beaconManager.bind(this);
```

OnBeaconConnect I do this:

```
  @Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    ArrayList<Identifier> identifiers = new ArrayList<>();

    // Set null to indicate that we want to match beacons with any value
    identifiers.add(null);
    // Represents a criteria of fields used to match beacon

    try {
        Region region = new Region("all-beacons-region", null, null, null);
        Region region2 = new Region("de3be3ce-4770-477b-8893-0f0e5aeb9b98", null, null, null);
        // Tells the BeaconService to start looking for beacons that match the passed Region object
        beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
        beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region2);
        beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region);
        beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region2);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Specifies a class that should be called each time the BeaconService gets ranging data, once per second by default
    beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(this);
    beaconManager.addMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
            Log.i(TAG, "I just saw an beacon for the first time!");
        }

        @Override
        public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
            Log.i(TAG, "I no longer see an beacon");
        }

        @Override
        public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
            Log.i(TAG, "I have just switched from seeing/not seeing beacons: " + state);
        }
    });

}
```

And didRangeBeaconsInRegion has this:

```
  @Override
public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
    if (beacons.size() > 0) {
        Log.i(TAG, "The first beacon I see is about " + beacons.iterator().next().getDistance() + " meters away.");
    }
}
```

But the monitorNotifier never gets called, and the rangeNotifier gets called, but beacons size is always 0.
Why don't I get the beacons here?

PS: I even tried hardcoding a beacon, using the UUID, but still I get nothing in monitorNotifier, and still size 0 in the range notifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you set up three beacon parsers for the Eddystone formats, but you are trying to detect a beacon sending out the iBeacon format.  (I say this based on the first identifier in the second region definition being a 16 byte UUID.)  If this is indeed what you are trying to do, please add a beacon parser for the iBeacon format.  You can find that here:

https://beaconlayout.wordpress.com/

Also, if you are trying to detect on Android 6+ make sure you have obtained location permissions otherwise you won't detect anything.  See here:

https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/requesting_permission.html

Comment: I have CoarseLocation permission. I will take a look at beaconlayout and see if I can understand. Yes, I am trying to get an iBeacon

Comment: This was it, adding this: `beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));` made it work

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
 public class BLEActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
private Handler mHandler;
private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 10000;
private BluetoothLeScanner mLEScanner;
private ScanSettings settings;
private List<ScanFilter> filters;
private BluetoothGatt mGatt;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mHandler = new Handler();
    if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "BLE Not Supported",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
    final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
            (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || !mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    } else {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            mLEScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
            settings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
                    .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
                    .build();
            filters = new ArrayList<ScanFilter>();
        }
        scanLeDevice(true);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mBluetoothAdapter != null && mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        scanLeDevice(false);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (mGatt == null) {
        return;
    }
    mGatt.close();
    mGatt = null;
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            //Bluetooth not enabled.
            finish();
            return;
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
    if (enable) {
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
                    mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                } else {
                    mLEScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);

                }
            }
        }, SCAN_PERIOD);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        } else {
            mLEScanner.startScan(filters, settings, mScanCallback);
        }
    } else {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        } else {
            mLEScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
        }
    }
}


private ScanCallback mScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
        Log.i("callbackType", String.valueOf(callbackType));
        Log.i("result", result.toString());
        BluetoothDevice btDevice = result.getDevice();
        connectToDevice(btDevice);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
        for (ScanResult sr : results) {
            Log.i("ScanResult - Results", sr.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
        Log.e("Scan Failed", "Error Code: " + errorCode);
    }
};

private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
        new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi,
                                 byte[] scanRecord) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.i("onLeScan", device.toString());
                        connectToDevice(device);
                    }
                });
            }
        };

public void connectToDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
    if (mGatt == null) {
        mGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, gattCallback);
        scanLeDevice(false);// will stop after first device detection
    }
}

private final BluetoothGattCallback gattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        Log.i("onConnectionStateChange", "Status: " + status);
        switch (newState) {
            case BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED:
                Log.i("gattCallback", "STATE_CONNECTED");
                gatt.discoverServices();
                break;
            case BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED:
                Log.e("gattCallback", "STATE_DISCONNECTED");
                break;
            default:
                Log.e("gattCallback", "STATE_OTHER");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        List<BluetoothGattService> services = gatt.getServices();
        Log.i("onServicesDiscovered", services.toString());
        gatt.readCharacteristic(services.get(1).getCharacteristics().get
                (0));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                     BluetoothGattCharacteristic
                                             characteristic, int status) {
        Log.i("onCharacteristicRead", characteristic.toString());
        gatt.disconnect();
    }
};
}
```